# Exceeding the maximum number of touches makes the program not to call the touchesEnded method?

Tags: ios, swift

Ive just started learning programming in general and ran into a problem: 
I have read some articles about that the iPhones are only capable of tracking 5 touches or so... But I realised that when I touch the screen with e.g. 7 fingers at once, my program-let stops working.

So, anyone knows, which parts of the code malfunctions when I am touching the screen way too many times at once?

(I am a newbie.)

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    nrTouches += touches.count
}
 override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        nrTouches -= touches.count
    }

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
}
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if nrTouches > 0 {
        touchingLabel.text = "touching"
    } else {
        touchingLabel.text = "not touching"
    }
}
```

So, in the case I am touching with 7 fingers at once, `"touching"` will be displayed all the time.
tankyuu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing touchesCancelled, which gets called when the 6th finger is put down:

```
override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) { 
    if let touches = touches {
        nrTouches -= touches.count // same logic as touchesEnded
    }
}
```

An interesting note: The iPad can handle 11 touch events. More on that [here](http://mattgemmell.com/ipad-multi-touch/).

Comment: so, i ve inserted that touchesCancelled func between the touchesMoved and update functions. However this makes the nrTouches reset to 0, regardless of the number of unneeded touches. So whenever reaching the 6th touch, it will show that I am not touching the screen at all.

Comment: That seems to be the OS level behavior. If too many touches (greater than 5), they are all cancelled...meaning they are no longer valid touches and are ignored. Not positive if this would happen with a custom gesture recognizer or if it's just an artifact of using the touch methods of the view, but I would expect the same behavior.